# how to add curvy tab in eclipse 4 RCP app

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

curvy tab in eclipse 4 RCP app. Even though i am adding SHOW_TRADITIONAL_STYLE_TABS=false to my plugin_customization.ini file. I aqm not able to find out any changes in the display of the tab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should be managed through the [E4 CSS engine](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/CSS), and your [associated CSS stylesheet for your RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/RCP/CSS) app should include something in the lines of:

```
.MPartStack {
  swt-tab-renderer: null;
  swt-selected-tabs-background: #FFFFFF #ECE9D8 100%;
  swt-simple: true;
  swt-mru-visible: true;
}
```

(from the page "[Eclipse4 CSS](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse4/CSS)", so it is for Eclipse4 itself, but could apply to your RCP as well)

If you have a **`swt-simple: false;`**, you should see curvy tabs.